# iOS8 WKWebview <meta viewport width=device-width> use the width of the whole screen

Tags: ios8, wkwebview

I'm using the normal code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
html { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

But on my `iPhone5c/iOS8` the webpage has a width of `320px` of the full screen width, not the `300px` of the WKWebview. What is that?